# JavaScript how to find closest class containing string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, closest

on click of a button I am trying to find the closest class containing a string. The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="feature I am the best">
  <div class="some style"> 
    <div class="new style">
      <button class="clickme">Click me </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my JavaScript is

```
$('.clickme').on('mouseup', function(event) {
  var description = $(this).closest('div[class*=:contains(feature)]').attr('class');
  console.log("Description "+description);
});
```

All I am getting in console is:

```
Description undefined
```

Comment: var description = $(this).closest('div[class*=:contains("feature")]').attr('class');

Comment: keep the string inside the double quotes

Answer (score 5):

Assuming it's really a substring check you want (not a class selector), you don't want the `contains(...)` bit, that's what `*=` means:

```js
$('.clickme').on('mouseup', function(event) {
  var description = $(this).closest('div[class*=feature]').attr('class');
  // Change here -------------------------------^^^^^^^
  console.log("Description "+description);
});
```

```html
<div class="feature I am the best">
  <div class="some style"> 
    <div class="new style">
      <button class="clickme">Click me </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If the string may contain quotes or other characters that don't fit the definition of a [CSS identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) (or if you just want to be cautious), put quotes around the value: `.closest('div[class*="feature I am"]')`

---

In your example, though, `feature` is a class so you'd want to use a class selector (`.closest("div.feature")`).

Answer (score 1):

Just use class selector with `.closest()` no need to use `:contains()`

```js
$('.clickme').on('mouseup', function(event) {
  var description = $(this).closest('.feature').attr('class');
  console.log("Description "+description);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature I am the best">
  <div class="some style"> 
    <div class="new style">
      <button class="clickme">Click me </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace contains with `class*="feature"`

```js
$('.clickme').on('mouseup', function(event) {
  var description = $(this).closest('div[class*="feature"]').attr('class');
  console.log("Description " + description);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature I am the best">
  <div class="some style">
    <div class="new style">
      <button class="clickme">Click me </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.clickme').on('mouseup', function(event) {
  var description = $(this).closest("[class^=feature]").prop('class');
  console.log("Description "+description);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feature I am the best">
  <div class="some style"> 
    <div class="new style">
      <button class="clickme">Click me </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the selector should be like this for wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

keep the string inside the double quotes

```
var description = $(this).closest('div[class*=:contains("feature")]').attr('class');
```